# How do I toss my turtle farther?

Tags: super-toss-the-turtle

I have unlocked everything and bought a stack of nuclear bombs.

I am currently using the most expensive in each category, but I'm not sure that it is the best, especially the Critical Bullets.

What combination of items is best?

Comment: @Ramirez: In case you haven't already, browse the Rimworld tag for similar goodies. (I also highly recommend [/r/ShitRimworldSays](https://www.reddit.com/r/ShitRimworldSays/top/?t=all), even more and better goodies) _Should I be friends with my neighbours? Do buried corpses rot normally? What happens if I install an AI in a prisoner's brain? How can I fertilize some of my eggs? How can I get rid of my prisoner's corpses?_

Answer (score 1):

I realy dont know if there is a "best" but my max without nukes is around 500k. Useing Golden Pistol/Cannon and a extra bullet.

To get the most out of your bullets you should aktivate them right bevore touching the ground. So even if your on a hight of 1.3k whait till you drop below 100m to aktivate the bullet to get the max out of it.

Also after testing the last item of each category Bombs, Jetpack, Cannon and Pistol give the strongest boots.